# Grid column contains int64 values but filter shows strings and doesn't work/

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, filtering, gridcontrol

We've got problem with filtering for some of our columns in devexpress gridcontrol. We add the column dynamically (bound-type column) to the grid. The values from the source objects are `long` type. In the cells it seems that values are fine (since they're aligned to the right without any custom formating on our side) however in filter popup values behave like strings.

For example data set like 1,2,5,11,22,37 the filter list is sorted like 1,11,2,22,5,37 (just like strings) and when we choose one of the available values the filtering does not work (i mean, grid becames empty). Even filters like "Non empty cells" does not work, but when we choose "empty cells" only few from few thousand rows are shown even if most of the cells have no values.

It is important to point out that only dynamically added columns behave that way, the few columns we create every time our module runs work as intended.

The data source is a container (List like).

We're using DevExpress 13.2.

Example of creating 'custom column'

```
void CreateColumn(GridColumn gridColumn, string fieldName = null, string caption = null, bool visible = true,
            bool readOnly = true, UnboundColumnType unboundType = UnboundColumnType.Bound,
            int columnWidth = int.MinValue, int minColumnWidth = int.MinValue)
{
    gridColumn.Caption = caption;
    if (fieldName != null)
        gridColumn.FieldName = fieldName;
    gridColumn.Visible = visible;
    gridColumn.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = readOnly;
    gridColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = !readOnly;
    gridColumn.UnboundType = unboundType;
    gridColumn.OptionsFilter.AllowAutoFilter = true;
    gridColumn.FilterMode = ColumnFilterMode.Value;
    gridColumn.OptionsFilter.AutoFilterCondition = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.AutoFilterCondition.Contains;
    if (columnWidth != int.MinValue)
    {
        gridColumn.Width = columnWidth;
        gridColumn.OptionsColumn.FixedWidth = true;
    }
    if (minColumnWidth != int.MinValue)
        gridColumn.MinWidth = minColumnWidth;
}

GridColumn gridColumn = new GridColumn();
CreateColumn(gridColumn, "someName", "someCaption", true, true);
View.Columns.Add(newGridColumn);
```

That's how it goes in our code (striped most of not related code just to give example process).

@edit
There's invalid cast exception when we add filter like this:

```
ColumnFilterInfo filter = GetFilter(); //cant really post code of this
ourGrid.MainView.ActiveFilter.Add(column, filter); // VS points here
```

Unfortunately it doesnt say what and where (except some 'lambda expression') exception is being thrown.

Of course `column` is the column mentioned above.

@edit
I've found new "tip". The FilterItem objects contain strings for sure, however they should contain long values. How can we influence the creation of these or atleast where to check why those are created like that (we dont do it manually)?

---

@Edit 19.11.2015
Alright, I had some breakthrough. The columns ('custom') thanks to our mechanism guess their type just fine. Then only problem is that infact our values which custom columns use are stored in `Dictionary<string,object>`-like collection and we think that thanks to `PropertyDescriptor` type for columns is fine, but for some reason `FilterItem` objects have `Value` of string. We belive that's because DX filter mechanism can't really guess type of "object" so it uses simple ToString on it so `FilterItem.Value` is string type instead column's data type.

How to overcome this?

Comment: What version of devex are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry, updated my question -  13.2

Comment: Seems to be working in the latest (15.1). Could you post a sample code that adds column dynamically

Comment: Well. all I can do is to confirm that it works in the latest version - dynamically adding a column using your code, automatic sort and filter - everything except your custom filter. If you are sure that the problem is not from your custom filter, I'm afraid you'll need to upgrade. Good luck.

Comment: I've found new "tip". The FilterItem objects contain strings for sure, they should contain long values. How can we influence the creation of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found the solution and the mistake was on our side. Column creation etc is fine. Somewhere deep, someone has changed value types.